# Nokia E75 Mail for Exchange

Tags: mobile-devices

- I have a SBS2003 runing Exchange Server 2003 SP2.
- My OWA has a godaddy certificate valid for 3 years to come installed. 
  HTTPS works fine for OWA.
- The certificate has also been copied into the Nokia E95
- I am trying to syncronize my Nokia E75 via Mail for Exchange to my mail account on the   Exchange server.

These are the steps i use:

- Menu > Email > New > Start > Select Internet Gateway > Than i enter the details:
  myemail@mydomain.com
  I select company email > Mail for Exchange > 
  In the domain menu i enter : mydomain
  In the username/password menu i enter : myusername/mypassword
  In the server menu i enter : mail.mydomain.com (where the DNS resolves into the server's  IP address)
  In the secure access i select : Internet / Secure / 443
- NOTE : port 443 has been opened on my SBOX and forwarded to the exchange server.
- On IIS > default website > properties > directory security > secure communications > edit >
  the "Require Secure Channel SSL" is enabled.

However, when i try to sync my phone i get the following error code: 
* Mail for Exch permissions illegal. Check permission configuration.
* The phone log gives the following information : Username or Password Illegal. Correct Username and/or Password in the profile options.

I've tried speaking with the Phone service support but they cannot identify the problem.

Any help will be much apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't tried to configure an Exchange Server to allow ActiveSync connections, I have used Nokia devices and Mail For Exchange to sync email, calendar, and contacts to my device.

I would direct you to the [Mail For Exchange Manuals](http://europe.nokia.com/appmanager/UnitedStatesEnglishEUROPE_NOKIA_COM_3/Get_support;JSESSIONID_NCOM=hDztLP1JyQ2BVDnLT8qnpnQr4rgDpprKvm1VnDPyy1GCK2sMjYJh!2119365227?_nfpb=true&_windowLabel=T318010986841239350077840&_pageLabel=P2439623&wsrp-urlType=blockingAction&wsrp-url=&wsrp-requiresRewrite=&wsrp-navigationalState=&wsrp-interactionState=_action%3D%2Fpageflows%2FEMEASupportTool%2Fbegin&wsrp-mode=&wsrp-windowState=), if you don't already have them.

I would also suggest trying the connection from a WiFi node inside your firewall, with a network sniffer attached to the line. Basically, simplify the network arrangement so that you can focus on the application configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the username field try with **username@domainname** where **domainname** is the AD domain where the user is validated

Comment: Hi, First thank you for your response. 
I've tried the following in the username field: username@domain domain@username 
username\domain 
domain\username 

I get the same error for all of them. Also worth mentioning - on my SBOX logs i see the IP of the phone connecting via port 443.

Comment: Okay here's a change.

I temporary disabled my SSL on OWA / Phone. and the syncronization works fine.

Aparently it is something related to the SSL option.